# cycleTime returning very incorrect times

Tags: turtlebot, roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to look at the timing actually performed by ros::Rate::sleep.

```
ros::Rate loop_rate{1};
while(ros::ok()) {
    //publish to a topic
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ROS_INFO("time: %f \n", loop_rate.cycleTime().toSec());
}
```

I am doing this on the turtlebot platform running ros indigo.

What I am seeing is that the expected cylce time of 1 second holds true in output, however I see outputs of the actual cycle time of 0.0005 seconds on average. However, through

```
rostopic hz <my topic>
```

I see a very accurate frequency of 1hz for publishing.

Any ideas on how to fix this/where I am going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256529/cycletime-returning-very-incorrect-times/) by [jdenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/29625/jdenny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what you are seeing is actually expected behaviour.

From the documentation of `cycleTime()` ([here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Rate.html#aa1fe97dde90f5c1b930aa0e940e8fe0e)):

> Get the actual run time of a cycle from start to sleep.

See also [here](https://github.com/strawlab/ros_comm/blob/6f7ea2feeb3c890699518cb6eb3d33faa15c5306/utilities/rostime/src/rate.cpp#L129-L130) for where this is calculated in `rostime/rate.cpp`:

> set the actual amount of time the loop took in case the user wants to know

So apparently your while-loop body takes `0.0005` seconds to execute. `loop_rate.sleep()` will just suspend your task/thread for the remainder of the second.

In other words: cycle time != number of iterations per second, but total time *per iteration*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/29625/jdenny/) on 2017-03-08**:
So to clarify, cycleTime() is approximately the time between calls to sleep, excluding the actual sleep-time. And by extension, what would be the best way to accurately time a sleep call? to get the frequency of publishing (actual time) in my cpp program -- expectedCycleTime() - cycleTime()?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-08**:
You'll have to clarify what you mean with "time a sleep call". `ros::Rate` already takes time spend doing work into account when calculating the time to sleep so you hit / get near your desired loop rate.

**Comment by [jdenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/29625/jdenny/) on 2017-03-08**:
I guess what I am asking is how do you accurately time the loop including the call to sleep with ros? I get that the loop_rate variable above already is close, but I am wanting to see actual time, not expected.

**Comment by [jdenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/29625/jdenny/) on 2017-03-08**:
Nevermind, I understand it now. I was confusing myself  over nothing. Thank you for your time and patience!